# A job interview question about map versus vector

Tags: c++

I've been asked during a job interview to code a solution for this issue:

> If a variable *k* equal to the sum of two elements of a vector *V*.

My answer was :

```
std::vector<int> V={1,3,7,9} ;
int k = 4;
bool test(false);
for(int i(0); i< V.size(); i++){
    for(int j(i+1); j<V.size(); j++){
        if(k == V[i]+V[j]) test=true;
    }
}
cout<<"the result is:" << test;
```

It works, yet the recruiter asked me to optimize it by the use of `map`, a container that I have not mastered enough to find the solution by myself, as I am a beginner in C++! May you please help me?

Comment: this is a popular problem called "2 sum" or "two sum".  my comment suggesting to look up sources does not qualify as an answer but if you look up some articles and videos on it perhaps you will find one that enlightens you as to why.

then if you have further questions like why a look up is O(1) then you can ask here

Comment: This is the [two-sum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), the very first problem on Leetcode and the internet is full of solutions.

Comment: You could certainly improve this solution by stopping all the looping once `test=true;`.  There's no benefit in checking whether it can be set to `true` additional times.

Comment: Yes indeed once it is true the looping must be stopped. A do.. while() would be more appropriate!

Comment: The basic insight is that you can reduce the (amortized) time complexity to `O(n)` by reducing the lookup for the second element to `O(1)` but the space complexity is now `O(n)` (in contrast to `O(1)` in your approach).

Comment: A good _job-interview-answer_ might be to say that with a vector size of 4, your brute-force O(n^2) iteration would do the job _just fine_.  Moving the numbers to a different container for better O( ) complexity should be considered once there are hundreds of numbers.

Comment: And sometimes thousands and tens of thousands. Computers are really good at doing stupid things very fast and sometimes the added smarts that get you O(1) complexity have overhead that takes a while to exceed what the computer can do with the brutal simplicity of a an approach with a less-favorable complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Yes, I want to be well prepared for my next Job interviews.

Comment: If the vector is sorted, you can do it in O(n) with only O(1) space, by having to iterators from the front and from the back.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some modified solutions based on "Approach 2: Two-pass Hash Table" and "Approach 3: One-pass Hash Table" of the [Two Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem on Leetcode.com (your solution is based on "Approach 1: Brute Force"):

```
std::vector<int> V = {1, 3, 7, 9};
std::map<int, size_t> M;
int k = 4;
bool test = false;
for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i) {
    M.insert(std::make_pair(V[i], i));
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i) {
    auto it = M.find(k - V[i]);
    if (it != M.end() && it->second != i) {
        test = true;
        break;
    }
}
cout << "the result is: " << test;
```

```
std::vector<int> V = {1, 3, 7, 9};
std::map<int, size_t> M;
int k = 4;
bool test = false;
for (size_t i = 0; i < V.size(); ++i) {
    if (M.find(k - V[i]) != M.end()) {
        test = true;
        break;
    }
    M.insert(std::make_pair(V[i], i));
}
cout << "the result is: " << test;
```

That being said, since you are not actually using the mapped indexes for anything, you can omit them and use `std::set` instead of `std::map`, eg:

```
std::vector<int> V = {1, 3, 7, 9};
std::set<int> S;
int k = 4;
bool test = false;
for (int num : V) {
    if (S.find(k - num) != S.end()) {
        test = true;
        break;
    }
    S.insert(num);
}
cout << "the result is: " << test;
```